# RegEx to match only {n} digits and not much or less surrounded by whatever

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match only {n} digits not more or less and may be surrounded by characters or special symbols

**example:**

suppose the {n} = {14}

*12345678901234*300 **OK**

12345678901234x21 **OK**

*123456789012345*300 **NOT OK**

12345678901234 **OK**

123456789012345 **NOT OK**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use negative [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert what is directly on the left and right is not a digit and match 14 digits:

```
(?<!\d)\d{14}(?!\d)
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cd%29%5cd%7b14%7d%28%3f!%5cd%29&i=12345678901234*300+OK%0d%0a%0d%0a12345678901234x21+OK%0d%0a%0d%0a*123456789012345*300+NOT+OK%0d%0a%0d%0a12345678901234+OK%0d%0a%0d%0a123456789012345+NOT+OK)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{14})(?:\D|$)
```

Here is a [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8uNsbz/3)